# How do I do timers in Java?

Tags: java, timer

I'm implementing the [x-modem protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMODEM) in Java. If there is a timeout while I'm receiving a packet then I have to send [negative acknowledgment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAK). I have to start a timer, and when the time is up then I send a message to the sender requesting file transfer from the begining.

But I'm not getting how to do timers in Java; may I see some sample code? Thank you.

Comment: plz rewrite your question so we can understand what you're talking about ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here some sample code from what I understood your question:

```
final Timer t = new Timer();
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         */
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do what you want
        }
    }, delay);

 if (gotResponse) t.cancel();
```

Where `delay` is the amount of milliseconds you want to wait before the Timer executes it's task.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the java.util.concurrent package, specifically the [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) class.

The problem with java.util.Timer is that it schedules one background thread to handle the timed tasks, and your tasks can queue up if the task itself takes a while to run (see [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) for details)

None of these give any real time guarantees.

This [book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601) is really good at explaining the usage of the java.util.concurrent package